# Show Component based on the url in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I have different component like about us, contact component e.t.c. But I don't know how to show or update component based on the url.

Index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Home from './components/Header';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Home from './components/About';
import Home from './components/Footer';

export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
        <Header />
        <Home />  # I want to make this component dynamic, so that I can change it based on the url selection
        <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Routes.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
...
...


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
            <Route exact path="/tag/:id" component={Tag} />
            <Route component={Error}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Header extends Component {

    state = {
        tags: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const tags = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];
        this.setState({ tags });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar variant="dark" expand="lg">
                    <Navbar.Brand href="/">Title</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="ml-auto">
                            <Nav.Link href="/" className="active">Home</Nav.Link>
                            <NavDropdown title="Tags" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                                {
                                    this.state.tags.map(
                                        tag => <NavDropdown.Item href={ '#/tag/'+tag.id }>{tag.tag_name}</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    )
                                }
                            </NavDropdown>
                            <Nav.Link href="#/about">About me</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#/search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Its already doing this. Why you want Index.js. If u need Header just add `Header` component in your app.js And if you want to render based on url you can simply do if else based on url you can render different component

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly what you wanted to do, you can call your Router component where you want to make Route.

But you should not use Link outside the Router, so in this scenario you need to wrap also your Header with your Router.

```
export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Router>
              <Header />
              <App /> (In here you can make Routing)
              <Footer />
            </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```